# RosMake Pocketsphinx issue?

Tags: ros, rosmake, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,
I am currently following this tutorial: [Pi Robot](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8Bboa9A3ElIJ:www.pirobot.org/blog/0022/+festival+ROS+electric&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

Its a cached link from google, and following the directions I've got everything except Pocketsphinx to build using this command:
**rosmake --rosdep-install pocketsphinx**

I have been stuck at this point for some time sadly. Anyone have any ideas?

---

System: Ros Electric Ubuntu 11.10

Error:

> [ rosmake] Packages requested are:
>
> ['pocketsphinx'] [ rosmake ] Logging
> to directory
> /Home/../../rosmake/rosmake_output...
>
> [ rosmake ] Expand args
> ['pocketsphinx'] to: []
>
> [ rosmake ] WARNING: the following args could not
> be parsed as stacks or packages:
> ['pocketsphinx']
>
> [ rosmake] ERROR: no arguments could be parsed into valid
> package or stack names.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28315/rosmake-pocketsphinx-issue?/) by [Markolise](https://answers.ros.org/users/1845/markolise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-02-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The directory that you checked the pocketsphinx code out into needs to be on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. To quickly check if this is your problem, `cd` into wherever you checked that SVN repository out into and type

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=`pwd`:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

In the same terminal window, try `rosmake --rosdep-install pocketsphinx`. If the package still isn't picked up, try running `rospack profile` and then the rosmake command again.

If it doesn't work yet again, update your question with the steps you executed in order and any further error messages.

If it did fix the problem, you can add a line similar to the one above to your `.bashrc` file such that that path is always on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. Note that in your `.bashrc` file, you'll have to use the actual path, not the `pwd` shortcut that worked above.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markolise](https://answers.ros.org/users/1845/markolise/) on 2012-02-23**:
Ok, it did work finally.
I had to add the export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=`pwd`:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to my setup.sh file
and re source that file in order to get it to build

The Environment setup wasn't to clear about where to put that file and I think thats where I was running into issues.

**Comment by [Markolise](https://answers.ros.org/users/1845/markolise/) on 2012-02-23**:
I had to move the setup.sh inside my ros_workspace folder and re-source that file to get it to build
Thanks so much for your help